# java regex with boundaries

Tags: java, regex

I need to search for words using a regular expression. Currently, I am using

```
String word = words.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[\\W]", "\\\\$0");            
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b(" + word + ")\\b");
```

where `word` is the regular word or with the wild card.

So far this expression works fine with regular words. But it fails to find a match using the wild card. For example, if I want to find all the words like matches, matched, matchstick, etc, using match(\w*), that should technically work, but it fails with the above expression ( with boundaries). How can I make it work?

Comment: `match(\w*)` will only capture the string after `match` in its capturing group.

Comment: A word boundary is implied after `\w*`. Your problem is that you mess up the pattern with `.replaceAll("[\\W]", "\\\\$0")`. You cannot pass a mixed of plain text + regex inside a single string search. All preprocessing must be done to the literal part before you add the `\w*` part. It is a problem with logic here.

Comment: So, the question is unclear now. To make it answerable, explain how your `words` are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is restoring `\w*` or `\w+` pattern in a regular expression use

```java
String word = words.replaceAll("\\W", "\\\\$0").replaceAll("\\\\{2}(w)\\\\?([*+])", "\\\\$1$2");
```

`.toLowerCase()` is not necessary, you are using `(?i)` case insensitive flag option.